# How to create an textarea editor for list for values?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, primevue

How to manage to create a textare editor for multivalue (array) input?
I mean I have model object like:

```
  "names": [
    "name 1",
    "name 2",
    "name 3"
  ]
```

Now I would like to be able to attach it to textarea, means textarea will display it line by line ... user should add/remove lines, and result will be set back as an array of lines to fit the model. Generally textarea accepts string as an input. Is there way a how to use some sort of getters/setters for a model, so getter will join array items with new line char and setter will split text area value by new line to make it array of lines?

Do you have any solution for this kind of problem?

EDIT: Need solution for https://primevue.org/textarea/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code it will join and split using \n:

**Option API Code**

```
<template>
    <textarea v-model="joinedItems"></textarea>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            myArray: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        joinedItems: {
            get() {
                return this.myArray.join('\n');
            },
            set(newValue) {
                this.myArray = newValue.split('\n');
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**Composition API Code**

```
<template>
    <textarea v-model="joinedItems"></textarea>
</template>

<script setup>
import {computed, ref} from "vue";

let myArray = ref(["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"])

const joinedItems = computed({
        get() {
            return myArray.value.join('\n');
        },
        set(newValue) {
            myArray.value = newValue.split('\n');
        }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store the names arr in a ref like this

```
const names = ref([
  "name 1",
  "name 2",
  "name 3"
])
```

Then you can have a textarea field where you change the array on input

```
<textarea 
  :value="names.join('\n').toString()" 
  @input="(e) => names = e.target.value.split('\n')">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Hmm, trying to adapt to https://primevue.org/textarea/ ... Not suitable solution